# Where should I keep my jsp file so that I can use my Name.java class for form-backing object?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, jsp

[image: Project structure]

I have a Name.java in my com.form.model package that has two String instance variables first_name and last_name. I want to have a jsp form that takes those two variables as input. Where exactly do I keep the Register.jsp file in my project directory so that I can map the form with my Name.java?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good pattern. Put all of your `.jsp` files in a folder called `/WEB-INF/view/` and create a sub-directory called `/form`. In my `application.properties` (I use gradle) I specify the location to serve JSP from:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

So let's say you have a JSP form:

```
/WEB-INF/view/form/register.jsp
```

So in a controller (I assumed you are using Spring) you can write:

```
/**
 * Serve the form
 */
@GetMapping("/register")
ModelAndView form() {

    return new ModelAndView("/form/register", "name", new Name())
}

/**
 * Handle submitted form
 */
@PostMapping("/register")
ModelAndView formCreate(@ModelAttribute Name name, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        // Handle form errors
    }

    // Add stuff to ModelMap or other processing
    // Return the form

    return new ModelAndView("/form/register", "name", name)
}
```